# Unreal Development Kit Layers Not Showing Up

Tags: unreal-development-kit

While using the UDK im trying to paint the height map with different texture, so ier setup the layers and texture samples but when i try and add them so i can paint them i get the blue and white boxes. Any help?

Screenshot of materials in the layers
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTsTI.jpg

Screen shot of the layers panel
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRo18.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem it appears i didn't set my Landscape Material in the Landscape Properties tab

http://www.xavierck.com/landscapetut/tut_008.png